# csvreader remove quotes from string when writing

Tags: java, csv

I'm using `csvreader/write` to create a csv file but when I try appending or writing to the csv with a `String` it also adds the double quotes.

```
import com.csvreader.CsvWriter;

public class CSVFile {
    private static final String defaultHeaders = "Node Name,Node IP,Object Name,DateTime";

    CsvWriter csvOutput = new CsvWriter(new FileWriter(user+currDateTime+".csv", true),',');    

    csvOutput.write(defaultHeaders);    
}
```

OUTPUT of csv is:

> "Node Name,Node IP,Object Name,DateTime"

I need:

> Node Name,Node IP,Object Name,DateTime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try the [writeRecord](http://javacsv.sourceforge.net/com/csvreader/CsvWriter.html#writeRecord%28java.lang.String%5b%5d%29) method?

```
private static final String defaultHeaders = {"Node Name", "Node IP", "Object Name", "DateTime"};
CsvWriter csvOutput = new CsvWriter(new FileWriter(user+currDateTime+".csv", true),',');    

csvOutput.writeRecord(defaultHeaders);
```